# Getting Apple Push HTTP/2 to work on Java 7

Tags: java, jboss, apple-push-notifications, tls1.2, http2

Our customer has a Jboss 7.1.1 AS running on Java 7u80 with an application that uses the Apple push notification framework to send out push notifications. It has been using the javapns lib for this. This has been working great so far, but now Apple is switching to Http/2 and the available 3rd party push libs are build for java 8+.

It is not an option to upgrade the server or the java runtime (JBoss 7.1.1 does not run on java 8).

I'm attempting to get push to work with OKHttp 3.12.12 (last OkHttp version before it also moved to java 8) and I have added dependencies on BouncyCastle in order to upgrade to TLS1.2 and the required ciphers, which for Apple Push I believe to be:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

My BouncyCastle dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bctls-jdk15to18</artifactId>
    <version>1.67</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15to18</artifactId>
    <version>1.67</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a startup class that looks like:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MCPStartUp {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", "BCJSSE");
            context.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
            SSLContext.setDefault(context);

            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) context.getSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();

            String[] protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();
            for (String string : protocols)
                System.out.println("protocol:" + string);
            for (String string2 : socket.getEnabledCipherSuites())
                System.out.println("enabled cipher: " + string2);
            for (String string2 : socket.getSupportedCipherSuites())
                System.out.println("supported cipher: " + string2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I look through the output I find that the ciphers that I need has been enabled.

```
enabled cipher: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

So far so good.

My test class for sending push notifications looks like:

```
public void test(String deviceToken) {
    // load push certificate
    FileInputStream certificate = new FileInputStream(APNS_CERT_PATH);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(certificate, APNS_CERT_PASS.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, APNS_CERT_PASS.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);

    KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0])
            .build();

    final Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(deviceToken).alertBody("Hello").build();

    Request.Builder rb = new Request.Builder().url("https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/" + deviceToken)
            .post(new RequestBody() {
                @Override
                public MediaType contentType() {
                    return MediaType.parse("application/json");
                }

                @Override
                public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                    sink.write(notification.getPayload().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                }
            })
            .header("apns-topic", "XXX")
            .header("content-length", notification.getPayload().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).length + "");

    Request request = rb.build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.code() == 200;
}
```

When I run my test class (invoked from a REST service), I can see in wireshark that the client hello handshake does NOT include the required ciphers:

[image]

(I am also a little confused about the TLS version, since there is both TLS 1.0 (blue box) and TLS 1.2 fields (red boxes). Im assuming that it is correctly using TLS1.2.)

I receive the following response:

[image]

THis is kind of expected, since my initial request does not include the required ciphers. But during startup, I have verified that they are indeed available in my java 7u80 runtime.

I have tried changing the code to explicitly use the ciphers:

```
ConnectionSpec connectionSpec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.RESTRICTED_TLS)
                .cipherSuites(
                        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
                        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256")
                .build();
        
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0])
                .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(connectionSpec))
                .build();
```

But this give me an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No usable cipher suites enabled
at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLContextSpi.getActiveCipherSuites(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient.getSupportedCipherSuites(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.tls.AbstractTlsClient.init(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketWrap.startHandshake(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketWrap.startHandshake(Unknown Source) [bctls-jdk15to18-1.67.jar:1.67.00.0]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:320) [okhttp-3.12.12.jar:]
```

What am I missing in order to make this work?
Let me know if you need more info. Hope you guys can help!

Best Regards
Rasmus

Comment: Can you run a newer JVM "next to" the JBoss application server and move the push functionality over there? Then change your code to talk to that JVM.

Comment: There are more differences in HTTP/2, I don't believe that proper cipher will be enough to make it work.  More realistic will be to manually rebuild OkHttp with source downgrade to Java7 or switch to Apache Httpclient library that not depend that much on jdk version.

Comment: We are considering running a parallel solution that only would handle the push functionality, but would prefer to keep it in the original application. As far as I understand, Apple will shutdown the old push api in March 2021, so we still have some time to find a solution.

Comment: OkHttp 3.12.12 should have support for HTTP/2, but we will consider trying the Httpclient library as well.

Comment: Depending on how this is hosted you could take advantage of external products too.  For example, in AWS your notification code could call a Lambda that calls the Apple API.  You can write the Lambda in Java, salvaging at least some of the code you have.  Sometimes you have to tell the client that it's time to upgrade.